# Loading derived class from DLL does not contain derived attributes

Tags: c++, oop, dll

i am working with DLLs and i am new to it.
I am trying to load derived class inherited from my Interface

```
class IModule{
public:
    virtual ~IModule(); // <= important!
    vector<String> getFunctions();


protected:
    vector<String> mFunctions;
};

class DllModule : public IModule {
public:
    DllModule() {
        this->mFunctions.push_back("Algorythm");

    };
private:
    int test;
};
```

and here I want send pointer to my application

```
extern "C" {
    IModule* CreateModule() {
        // call the constructor of the actual implementation
        IModule * module = new DllModule;
        // return the created function
        return module;
    }
}
```

In my application after I load it

```
f_GetFunctions funci = (f_GetFunctions)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "CreateModule");
    if (!funci) {
        std::cout << "Could not locate function CreateModule" << std::endl;
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
        return nullptr;
    }
    IModule* module = funci();
```

I expect the mFunction populated, but its like new instance of IModule instead of DllModule loaded from DLL. All I want is loop at mFunctions and populate my combobox in QT_App.

Can somebody help me? What's wrong with my expectations?

Thank you very much.

(Everything is done in Windows10)

**Edit1:** Changed types to minimal (sorry for that)
Function => String

**Edit2:** I completly forgot about assigning pointer

Comment: What is `Function`? Is it an alias for a string-type?

Comment: The overall structure looks ok, but it's definitely not a minimal code example, there are already some mysterious types included. Do a simple test with one integer attribute, that gets set in the constructor.

Comment: I edited it a bit. Changed type Function to String.
And instead of return funci(); inserted the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent my problem.
I used QLibrary.Load() instead of LoadLibraryA and it did exactly what i wanted.